# "too much data for sort()" on a small collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When trying to do a find and sort on a mongodb collection I get the error below. The collection is not large at all - I have only 28 documents and I start getting this error when I cross the limit of 23 records.

The special thing about that document is that it holds a large ArrayCollection inside but I am not fetching that specific field at all, I am only trying to get a DateTime field.

```
db.ANEpisodeBreakdown.find({creationDate: {$exists:true}}, {creationDate: true} ).limit(23).sort( { creationDate: 1}

{ "$err" : "too much data for sort() with no index. add an index or specify a smaller limit", "code" : 10128 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem here is a 32MB limit and you have no index that can be used as an "index only" or "covered" query to get to the result. Without that, your "big field" still gets loaded in the data to sort.

Easy to replicate;

```js
var string = "";
for ( var n=0; n < 10000000; n++ ) {
   string += 0;
}

for ( var x=0; x < 4; x++ ) {
    db.large.insert({ "large": string, "date": new Date() });
    sleep(1000);
}
```

So this query will blow up, unless you limit to 3:

```js
db.large.find({},{ "date": 1 }).sort({ "date": -1 })
```

To overcome this:

1. Create an index on date (and other used fields) so the whole document is not loaded in your covered index query:

   ```js
   db.large.ensureIndex({ "date": 1 })
   db.large.find({},{ "_id": 0, "date": 1 }).sort({ "date": -1 })

   { "date" : ISODate("2014-07-07T10:08:33.067Z") }
   { "date" : ISODate("2014-07-07T10:08:31.747Z") }
   { "date" : ISODate("2014-07-07T10:08:30.391Z") }
   { "date" : ISODate("2014-07-07T10:08:29.038Z") }
   ```
2. Don't index and use aggregate instead, as the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) there does not suffer the same limitations as the document actually gets altered before passing to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/).

   ```js
   db.large.aggregate([
       { "$project": { "_id": 0, "date": 1 }},
       { "$sort": {"date": -1 }}
   ])

   { "date" : ISODate("2014-07-07T10:08:33.067Z") }
   { "date" : ISODate("2014-07-07T10:08:31.747Z") }
   { "date" : ISODate("2014-07-07T10:08:30.391Z") }
   { "date" : ISODate("2014-07-07T10:08:29.038Z") }
   ```

Either way gets you the results under the limit without modifying cursor limits in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I was looking for a way to sort the data without adding a new index and the aggregate works just fine.

Comment: @user3811709 There really is no difference in the performance, both evaluate the same but just differently. Actually the way the aggregation pipeline is "optimized" it would not matter in "this case" if the `$sort` was specified before the `$project`, as that case would be handled to do exactly the same thing by "projecting" first.

Answer (score 0):

Without an index, the size you can use for a sort only extends over `shellBatchSize` which by default is 20.

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 23;
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Isn't DBQuery a Java object? Also sort without an index is limited to 32mb RAM

Comment: Nope. Have a look at [the docs here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#executing-queries) (it is way down).

Comment: Ok, they must have changed the name then

Comment: I think what you are thinking of is `db.foo.find().batchSize(23)`, which also should work.

Comment: Indeed I am used to batchsize being on the cursor, good to know they haven't taken that out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that projection in this particular scenario still loads the entire document, it just sends it to your application without the large array field.

As such MongoDB is still sorting with too much data for its 32mb limit.